# Разница между f:validatorlength и maxLength в jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Немогу нагуглить разницы. Что если объявить их вместе для inputtextarea? Первое это длина одного слова, а второе просто длина inputtext? Подскажите кому не сложно пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Атрибут `maxlength` в процессе рендеринга просто превратиться в одноимённый атрибут поля ввода html. Следить за соблюдением ограничения, устанавливаемого этим атрибутом, будет браузер, но ничего не мешает пользователю изменить значение атрибута или отправить запрос не из браузера.

А тег `<f:validateLength />` указывает JSF о необходимости проверки **на стороне сервера** длинны присланного значения поля ввода.

Лучше всего сочетать оба варианта.

Comment: Очень странно idea распознает maxlength но он не работает.